# Simple auto_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I wrote my own simple `auto_ptr` class, but detected some magic.

**C++ Header file**

```
class A {
private:
    int data;
public:
    A(int data);
    void print() const;
};

class auto_ptr_ref;

class auto_ptr {
private:
    A* ptr = 0;
public:
    auto_ptr(A* p);
    auto_ptr(auto_ptr& p);
    auto_ptr(auto_ptr_ref p);
    ~auto_ptr();
    auto_ptr& operator =(auto_ptr& p);
    void release();
    operator auto_ptr_ref();
    A& operator*() const;
    A* operator->() const;
};

class auto_ptr_ref {
private:
    auto_ptr* ptr;
public:
    auto_ptr* get();
    auto_ptr_ref(auto_ptr* ptr);
};
```

---

**C++ Source file**

```
A::A(int data) : data(data) {}

void A::print() const {
    printf("%d\n", data);
}

auto_ptr::auto_ptr(A* p) : ptr(p) {}

auto_ptr::auto_ptr(auto_ptr& p) {
    ptr = p.ptr;
    p.release();
}

auto_ptr::auto_ptr(auto_ptr_ref p) {
    *this = *(p.get());
    p.get()->release();
}

auto_ptr::~auto_ptr() {
    delete ptr;
}

void auto_ptr::release() {
    ptr = NULL;
}

auto_ptr::operator auto_ptr_ref() {
    return auto_ptr_ref(this);
}

auto_ptr& auto_ptr::operator =(auto_ptr& p) {
    if (ptr != NULL)
        delete ptr;
    ptr = p.ptr;
    p.release();
    return *this;
}

A& auto_ptr::operator*() const {
    return (*ptr);
}

A* auto_ptr::operator->() const {
    return ptr;
}

auto_ptr_ref::auto_ptr_ref(auto_ptr* ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}

auto_ptr* auto_ptr_ref::get() {
    return ptr;
}
```

---

**Test 1**

```
int main() {
    auto_ptr ptr(auto_ptr(new A(10)));
    ptr->print();
    return 0;
}
```

Code compiles and prints `10`.

---

**Test 2**

```
int main() {
    A* data = new A(10);
    auto_ptr ptr(auto_ptr(data));
    ptr->print();
    return 0;
}
```

Code doesn't compiles.

error: request for member ‘print’ in ‘ptr’, which is of non-class type ‘auto_ptr(auto_ptr)’

---

**Test 3**

```
int main() {
    A* data = new A(10);
    auto_ptr ptr((auto_ptr(data)));
    ptr->print();
    return 0;
}
```

And this code compiles and prints `10`!

Could you please explain what happens in the second test case? Why does 'ptr‘ have  ‘auto_ptr(auto_ptr)’ type?

Comment: Why did you write your own `auto_ptr`? C++ deprecated it (for being a dangerous and unintuitive hack of a design-compromise), the moment they could specify something better (`unique_ptr`).

Comment: Cause it was my home task)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

```
auto_ptr ptr(auto_ptr(data));
```

Declares a function named 'ptr' that has a parameter named 'data' of type 'auto_ptr' and that returns a value of type 'auto_ptr'.

So, don't make this mistake)